# multiple components accessing same data at same time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

In my angular application i have a dashboard which is composed of 3 different components

1)Left menu component

2) right menu component

3) let's say central component

All the three need access to same api response.
Earlier i had coded in such a way that when each of these component is loaded the settings api is hit and data is fetched.So that was a total of 3 api calls for the same data.
I want to change this

I want to hit the api once and the data must be available for all the three components while they load.

i tried event emitter but the api was not getting hit only.

below is the api call.

```
getUserSettings(): Observable<any> {
    var userSettUrl = this.baseUrl + this.ngAuth.getApiUrl('settings');
    let httpHeader = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      })
    };
    return this.http.get(userSettUrl, httpHeader)
      .map((res: any) => {
        var obj = res;
        return this.userSettings = obj.settings;
      });
  }
```

In each of the component ngOnInit() the subscription is added.
I want to optimize it

Please Guide

Thanks
Shruti

Comment: use ngrx store to maintain the shared data [example here](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app)

Comment: Call the API in parent component and pass it down to children.

Comment: `shareReplay()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimized solution will be to create an cachedResponse,thus you hit once and get a copy from that for other components.if api response is already there.I will share the example i used in angular 5.

```
  //In service
    cacheCommonSuccess$: Observable<any>;

     public getSuccessCommonMsg() {
        if (!this.cacheCommonSuccess$) {
          this.cacheCommonSuccess$ = this.requestSuccessCommonMsg();
        }
        return this.cacheCommonSuccess$;
      }



   private requestSuccessCommonMsg() {
    const url = this.API_BASE_URL + '/api/successmessages.json';
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      map(response => response[0]), shareReplay()
    );
  }


//In all three components 



 // To get stored success msgs from shared component
  getSuccessCommonMsgs() {
    this._SharedServiceService.getSuccessCommonMsg().subscribe(res => {
      this.apiResponseGSuccess = res;      
    });
  }
```

Or you can call this api in parent component and pass this to all child components ,if possible (like in react js).

Comment: you can do it much simpler with `shareReplay(1)`

Comment: 1 is not necessary, but if it were a not completing stream it would replay the whole stream for each subscriber instead of just last value which may be not desired.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a parent component , lets call it **Dashboard** having **Left menu component**. **right menu component** and **central component** as child component.
2. Make a call to **getUserSettings** under dashboard component(on ngOnInit()).
3. Pass api response data to child component using **@Input @Output** decorator or 
   just use the concept of **Behaviour Subject(Service)**  to share data between component.

**Note**. If you using **Behaviour Subject(Service)** there is no need to have a parent-child relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to use `shareReplay(1)` this will automatically put your response into a `ReplaySubject` under the hood and all components subscribing will receive the value from replay subject instead of doing an API call.
So your service can do the following:

```
getUserSettings(): Observable<UserSettings> {
    var userSettUrl = this.baseUrl + this.ngAuth.getApiUrl('settings');
    let httpHeader = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      })
    };
    return this.http.get(userSettUrl, httpHeader).pipe(
      map((res: any) => obj.settings),
      shareReplay(1)
    );
  }
```

Then in your components you can simply subscribe to this and get your results by either subscribing directly or by using `async` pipe. When subscribing directly make sure to unsubscribe and handle change detection if you're using `OnPush` strategy which I recommend.

Of course other alternatives can work too. E.g. ngrx was mentioned, it can be a good approach to share application wide data, but it requires much more effort to put together.